# What's the constructor of a subclass that does not have an explicit one?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

The below code shows that an ES6 subclass which does not specify a constructor does not share it with its superclass. Yet, the superclass constructor is being called with all of the arguments:

```js
class SuperClass {
  constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {}

console.log(
  "Is the subclass constructor the same as the superclass?",
  SubClass.prototype.constructor === SuperClass.prototype.constructor
); // false

new SubClass(1, 2, 3); // 1 2 3
```

Does JavaScript add a default constructor implementation when it's not specified? I guess it adds a constructor like this:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

But I'm not sure and can't find any authoritative info about it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor   IOW: if it's a base class `constructor() {}`  but if it's derived it is indeed how you imagined.

Comment: Ok so my guess was correct... Not sure why I didn't find this myself, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. In a subclass, the constructor created for you if you don't provide one explicitly is:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

This is defined in Step 14 in [*Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) in the specification.